# Query dictionary for specific class members c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ddd
{
    public class FPSData
    {
        private double minFPS;
        private double maxFPS;
        private double averageFPS;

        #region Properties

        public double MinFPS
        {
            get { return minFPS; }
            set { minFPS = value; }
        }
        public double MaxFPS
        {
            get { return maxFPS; }
            set { maxFPS = value; }
        }
        public double AverageFPS
        {
            get { return averageFPS; }
            set { averageFPS = value; }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        public FPSData(double min, double max, double avg)
        {
            minFPS = min;
            maxFPS = max;
            averageFPS = avg;
        }
    }
}
```

In my main function, I'm declaring the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<uint, FPSData> trying = new Dictionary<uint, FPSData>();

        FPSData m1 = new FPSData(1, 2, 3);
        FPSData m2 = new FPSData(4, 5, 6);
        FPSData m3 = new FPSData(7, 8, 9);

        trying.Add(101, m1);
        trying.Add(102, m2);
        trying.Add(103, m3);

        Console.WriteLine("sdfgh");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a dictionary (`Dictionary<uint, doubule>`) for, let's say, only the minimum values.

Meaning, that my dictionary will have the following:

```
101, 1
102, 4
103, 7
```

I tried many variations of `LINQ`, but just couldn't get it right. Is it possible?

Comment: +1 for `Console.WriteLine("sdfgh");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.ToDictionary()` [(MSDN Documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var minimumValues = trying.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.MinFPS);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<uint, double> result = trying.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value.MinFPS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Dictionary<uint, double> minimumFPS = trying.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.MinFPS);
```

Comment: -1 Because you obviously copied Chritos' answer with `Dictionaty`. You could at least fix the spelling mistakes before pasting.

Comment: pff yeah sure... -.- Chuck norris will roundhouse kick you for this :P

Comment: @gleng the answers are within 1 minute of each other, he was likely still typeing when both of you posted (also Christo's code is wrong as he never declares a variable (till his edit just now))

Comment: @ScottChamberlain He knows he was busted. :)

Comment: @Scott yeah I just noticed that I hadn't declare a variable. Thanks !